# porque en mi codigo no logro remplazar un punto por una coma? javascript

Tags: javascript, float, replace

buenas me gustaria saber porque mi codigo no pasa de el punto "." a una coma "," es que me gustaria mostrar el resultado con una , y no con un punto . este es el codigo aqui lo que intento hacer es remplazar el punto que ven en la variable monto y imprimirla abajo  con una coma

````
var monto = "0.00178938";
var completo = "";
var anadir = "";

for (var i = 0; i <= monto.length -1; i++) {

if (monto[i] != "on") {
    var punto = ",";
    if (monto[i] === ".") {
        monto[i] = monto[i].replace(".",",");

        monto[i] = punto;

        console.log("esto deberia ser una coma ",monto[i]);
    }

    completo = completo + monto[i];

    anadir = completo;

}

anadir = parseFloat(anadir);


}console.log(anadir);```
````

Comment: No entiendo tu condicion?, porque pones `monto[i] != "on"`, si lo que intentas comparar son solo numeros en una cadena de texto?, ademas `monto[i]` solo puede devolverte un caracter, no dos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En la mayoria de lenguajes de programación **NO** se usa la `,` si no el punto (`.`) para describir numeros decimales, por lo tanto, aquello que quieres hacer **es imposible** puesto que el lenguaje en si **NO** te lo permite.

A lo que me refiero es que javascript no reconoce la (`,`) como una caracter valido para ser asignado como **NUMERO** en una variable, he aqui la prueba:

```js
const numeroFlotante = 3,6;
console.log(numeroFlotante);
```

Por tanto aquello que pides **no se puede lograr** si lo que deseas es poder usar eso luego como un numero.

Si deseas usar eso como un numero para hacer operaciones matematicas, no te queda mas remedio que simplemente dejarlo asi con el punto y pasarlo a flotante directamente:

```
var monto = "0.00178938";
monto = parseFloat(monto);
```

En caso de que enrealidad solo quieras mostrar el resultado en formato de cadena **SIN POSIBILIDAD** de hacer operaciones aritméticas, lo que puedes hacer es primero parsear el numero:

```
var monto = "0.00178938";
monto = parseFloat(monto);
```

Y despues de que tengas `monto` como un numero decimal, hacer las operaciones que necesites, luego tratar el numero para que todos los puntos sean reemplazados por comas, para ello deberas convertir primero tu numero resultado de nuevo a un string:

```
anadir = anadir.toString();
anadir = anadir.replace(/./g, ",");

//No uses parseFloat o parseInt luego, dara una excepcion
```

**Y no, no hay forma de usar la coma para tratar ahora la variable añadir como numero decimal**, si intentas hacer alguna operacion matematica con anadir el resultado sera `NaN`.

Comment: Si tienes razon, ya hice todo siguiendo al pie de la letra como me dijiste y tienes razón, gracias por responder a mi pregunta

Comment: De nada,  recuerda que si te fue de ayuda esta respuesta, puedes darla como aceptada,  dandole al boton que parece un chulo.

Comment: ya le dí al chulito gracias

Answer (score 0):

Claro que se puede siempre y cuando no sea un valor que tenga que manipular el usuario directamente con su teclado, tienes la posibilidad de tener una variable tipo Numero en tu código e imprimirla con el formato que mas te acomode en el front

aquí un ejemplo rápido (probado con IE 11 y superior)

```
const numberX = 1334223.4323;
const numberY = 0.432312321;

console.log('numberX: ', numberX.toLocaleString('de-DE'));
console.log('numberY: ', numberY.toLocaleString('de-DE'));
```

Y un poco de documentacion
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString#Using_options

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Intl/NumberFormat